# Need to move pattern in a file to different location in the same file using perl?

Tags: perl, file

My input file has format like

```
hidestart 
machine learning
hideend

rule abc {
  hidestart
   Keep Learning
  hideend
   -abc [ time=good] 
}

rule abc1 {
   Keep Learning

   -abc1 [ time1=fail] 
}


Rule “abc” { 
   hidestart 
    dp a.E_t_C1 temp –be_good NL LP -expr " (cnt(a.E_t_C1) > 0) ? expr(- (minus (pt(a.E_t_C1,ab)) / at(temp)*fr/pr_1)) : 1 " < 0 > 1 
   hideend 
   ….. 
   -CDE [ ABC_TYPE = “temp_EOL”] 
   -CDE [ TMP_RUL = “a.E” ] 
   .. .. .. 
   -comment "keepTrying" 
}
```

And I wish to move hideend which lies inside the rule block to the end and just before curly braces. This hideend should be inserted/moved only if the rule block has hidestart command. Also, hidestart/hidened which lies outside of this rule block should be kept intact.

Expected Output:

```
hidestart 
machine learning
hideend

rule abc {
  hidestart
   Keep Learning
   -abc [ time=good] 
  hideend
}
rule abc1 {
   Keep Learning

   -abc1 [ time1=fail] 
}

Rule “abc” { 
   hidestart 
    dp a.E_t_C1 temp –be_good NL LP -expr " (cnt(a.E_t_C1) > 0) ? expr(- (minus (pt(a.E_t_C1,ab)) / at(temp)*fr/pr_1)) : 1 " < 0 > 1 

   ….. 
   -CDE [ ABC_TYPE = “temp_EOL”] 
   -CDE [ TMP_RUL = “a.E” ] 
   .. .. .. 
   -comment "keepTrying" 
  hideend
}
```

My current code, is actually removing hideend which lies outside of the block and also adding hideend to the rule block where I don’t have hidestart. Please help me fixing below code

```
!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict();
use warnings();
use Data::Dumper;
my $ruleData=0;
my $goldenData = $ARGV[0];
open( $fopen, "< $goldenData") or die "cannot open $!";
while(<$fopen>) {
 if ( $_ =~ /^\s*rule(.+)/gi ) {
   print "rule$1\n";
   while($tmp=<$fopen> ) {
     if ( $tmp =~ /^\s*hideend/gi ) { next; }
     if ( $tmp =~ /^\s*\}/gi ) {
        print "hideend\n$1\}\n";
     } else {
         print "$tmp";
     }
   }
  close($tmp);
 } else {
    print "$_";
 }
}
close($fopen);
```

Let me know if there any questions.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Divesh

Comment: 1) Your code as it stands cannot compile. It is important that you show the _actual_ code that gives you trouble. 2) Here's one way.  Open two files, one to read your input the other to write the output. As you go through input lines write them to output. When you get to `hidestart` set a flag. Keep going. If you get to brace unset the flag. When you get to `hideend` if flag is true don't write it to the output file. When you get to the closing brace write `hideend` and the brace. Unset the flag. Keep going to the end. The output file is your result (save for some detail I may have forgotten).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict();
use warnings();
use Data::Dumper;
my $ruleData=0;
my $goldenData = $ARGV[0];
open(IN, "<$goldenData") or die "cannot open $!";
local $/; $_=<IN>; my $tmp=$_;
close(IN);

my $CurBrLoopMany = qw/((?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*)/;

my ($_pre,$_match,$_post) = "";
while($tmp=~m/rule([\"A-z\s]*)\{$CurBrLoopMany\}/gis)
{
    $_pre = $_pre.$`; $_match = $&; $_post = $';
    $_match=~s/\s*hideend//g;
    $_match=~s/\}/ hideend \n}/i;
    $_pre = $_pre.$_match; $tmp = $_post;
}
if(length $_pre) {  $tmp = $_pre.$_post;  }

print $tmp;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ssr1010. This code actually not working on my actual file. My txt file also have  double quotes in the string after rule. Here, is the sample snippet  of input file                                                                                    

rule "abc" {
hidestart
   Keep Learning
hideend
   -abc [ time=good]
}

Please let me know if there any questions.

Regards,
Divesh

Comment: Still not working on actual case

Here is some more details about the actual file content 

Rule “abc” {
hidestart
    dp a.E_t_C1 temp –be_good NL LP -expr "  (cnt(a.E_t_C1) > 0) ?   expr(- (minus (pt(a.E_t_C1,ab)) / at(temp)*fr/pr_1))   :   1    " < 0 > 1
hideend
  …..
    -CDE [ ABC_TYPE = “temp_EOL”]
    -CDE [ TMP_RUL = “a.E” ]

..
..
..
-comment "keepTrying"
}

Comment: Expecting people to read code samples in a comment is a terrible idea. Far better to add the details to your original question and add a comment directing us to look there.

Comment: `qw/((?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*)/` - Any code that contained that without a comment wouldn't get past any code review I was running! Also, did you mean `qr/.../` instead of `qw/.../`?

Comment: @user3093942: Better you should ask your question properly may be sometimes providing answer will based on your question only.

Answer (score 0):

This works on your sample file. And, hopefully, the comments make it clear what's going on so that you can fix any problems that you find.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($found_hidestart, $found_hideend);

while (<>) {
  # Only process within a rule block
  if (/^rule\s+\S+\s+{/i .. /^}/) {
    # If we find 'hidestart' remember that
    if (/\bhidestart\b/) {
      $found_hidestart = 1;
    }

    # If we find 'hideend' (and have already found 'hidestart')
    # remember that and don't print this line.
    if (/\bhideend\b/ && $found_hidestart) {
      $found_hideend = 1;
      next; # skip printing
    }

    # If we're at the end of a block and we've previously found
    # both 'hidestart' and 'hideend', then print 'hideend'.
    if (/^}/) {
      print "  hideend\n" if $found_hidestart and $found_hideend;
      # Forget what we've previously found
      $found_hidestart = $found_hideend = 0;
    }
  }
  print;
}
```

It's written as a Unix filter - so it reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT. That's so much more flexible than opening explicit filenames. Assuming this is in a file called `reformat`, you would call it like this:

```
$ ./reformat < your_existing_file > your_new_file
```

**Update:** I've updated the regex slightly so it deals with your expanded example.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Unfortunately, your code is also not working. I've updated the sample of my input file in first posting. Please try that sample file.